# swift Make UIButtons input text into a textbox

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I was wondering if it is possible to make a UIButton input text into a text box when pressed

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

var textBox = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, w, h))
    textBox.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
    self.view.addSubview(textBox)

var button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, w, h))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Is there a way to make the var button input text to the text box (var textBox)

Comment: Why do you want such a button? What is the usage?

Comment: making a calculator UI

Comment: @Peter would you know a possible way?

Comment: try to not be lazy, it will get you farther on your journey:  https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=swift%20calculator%20tutorial

Comment: I think you can create awesome class for the button. why did not you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your selector method added to your button using [addTarget](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:)

```
var textBox = UITextField!
var button = UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textBox = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, w, h))
    textBox.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
    self.view.addSubview(textBox)
    button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, w, h))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    button.addTarget(self, 
        action:#selector(buttonTapped),
        forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

func buttonTapped(object:AnyObject) {
    textBox?.text = "your text"
}
```

Comment: the function buttonTapped cannot detect the text box in viewdidload

Comment: @Ice3343 sorry for typos, responding using iPad and auto correct is messing up the code. The buttonTapped method should be outside viewdidload var button: UIButton! Should also be outside viewdidload.